# Kafka-Connect : Getting an unrecognised error when starting a S3 Sink Connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-cluster, s3-kafka-connector

I am trying to set up my 3rd worker for a Kafka Connect cluster with 3 nodes. The worker runs properly on this 3rd node and I'm able to make REST calls to get existing connectors (which for now I have 2, one on each node). However, when I try to make the POST call to create the 3rd connector with the following command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @test-s3-sink-config.json http://<my-host>:<my-port>/connectors
```

I get this TimeoutException response:

```
{"error_code":500,"message":"IO Error trying to forward REST request: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout"}
```

And when I look into the worker stack trace it says the following:

```
[2020-10-20 18:27:04,062] INFO AbstractConfig values:
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:354)
[2020-10-20 18:27:19,081] ERROR IO error forwarding REST request:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient:143)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:711)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:125)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.completeOrForwardRequest(ConnectorsResource.java:369)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.createConnector(ConnectorsResource.java:164)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.jav
a:52)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherPr
ovider.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect Timeout
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$Connect.run(ManagedSelector.java:812)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
```

The first log of the trace is what is bothering me, because I don't see any relevant information about what I'm doing wrong, and the second log is just the TimeoutException. I looked everywhere to find someone who had a similar problem, or to learn about the 'AbstractConfig' class but couldn't find anything useful, [this is the AbstractConfig class](http://www.howsoftworks.net/kafkclie/2.0.0/AbstractConfig) from Kafka (I'm using Kafka version 2.0.0).

Finally, here is the config file I'm using:

```
{"name":"s3-connector-orderbooks",
"config":{
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
"file":"snapshots-test",
"format.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
"flush.size":"1000000",
"tasks.max":"1",
"topics":"binance-full-snaps-test",
"timezone":"UTC",
"storage.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
"rotate.schedule.interval.ms":"3600000",
"s3.bucket.name":"pfc-data",
"timestamp.extractor":"Record",
"partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner",
"locale":"en-US",
"s3.compression.type":"gzip"
}
}
```

If you feel like there's any additional information I should be including feel free to ask for it, I'm rather new to stack overflow.

I would love to know if anybody ever encounter something like this, or if someone has some idea of what could be causing the issue here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a Kafka connect cluster, the leader node is the one who is responsible for serving REST request. Therefore, it is worth checking whether leader node can reach all available worker nodes in the cluster. You can check your `rest.advertised.host.name` in your `distributed.properties` to make sure whether advertised host name of the node is reachable within the connect cluster. There is a well written article on this topic by Robin Moffatt in his [blog](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/). Please read it to get a good insight.